# How to get the expected result from the table, in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

Main table

```
PrimaryID  | SecondaryID | PrimaryTime | SecondaryTime  
------------------------------------------------------
100        | 101         |   10        | 50 
101        | 103         |   20        | 60 
102        | 100         |   30        | 70 
100        | 102         |   40        | 80
```

Expected output:

```
ID   | Total TIME 
-----------------
100  | 120 
101  | 70
102  | 110
103  | 60
```

Comment: I for one can't follow the formula/logic to achieve the Total_time in your expected output from your main table.  Take the time to explain what it is you're trying to achieve and you may get better responses to your question.

Comment: based on primaryid and secondaryid i need total time, example  for 100 sum is 10+70+40

Comment: @xQbert: agreed. I think the logic is that the IDs are merged into one column, and the corresponding times added. For example, ID 100 appears in rows 1 (primary), 3 (secondary) and 4 (primary). Corresponding times are 10, 70 and 40, which add to 120.

Comment: @rock: Is this mySQL or SQL Server? Title and tags don't match...

Comment: this is supposed to be in mssql

Answer (score 2):

Here we simply output a 2 columns subquery from the 4 columns table, then sum up the values fore each distinct primary or secondary Id :

```
CREATE TABLE MainTable (PrimaryID int, SecondaryID int, PrimaryTime int, SecondaryTime int)
INSERT MainTable VALUES (100,101,10,50), (101,103,20,60), (102,100,30,70), (100,102,40,80)

;WITH MainCTE AS (
    SELECT PrimaryID ID, PrimaryTime Time FROM MainTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SecondaryID ID, SecondaryTime Time FROM MainTable
)

SELECT ID, SUM(Time) [Total TIME] FROM MainCTE GROUP BY ID
```

This is quite simple, the point was to figure out what you were asking for.

Comment: Explanation may help others.  While this appears to work, I'm not a big fan of all SQL answers.  The trick here is creating two data sets consisting of Id and time of each and union the results together, allowing SQL native aggregation to work.

Comment: Thank you xQbert, I was experimenting "all SQL answers", no luck, comments help you're right (edit done.)